# what is the difference between `Matrix.setRotate` and `Matrix.postRotate`

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap

I'm trying to rotate a given bitmap using android Matrix object.

I want to send it to rotated to my server and I'm using Android API8.

Should i use `Matrix.setRotate` or `Matrix.postRotate` ?

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html), [`setRotate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRotate%28float%29) sets a particular **absolute** rotation (around either `(0,0)` or some other user-supplied point), while [`postRotate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postRotate%28float%29) **adds to** the rotation of the matrix it is called on.

The question of *which one should I use* is best answered by trying each and seeing which one gives you the result that *you* want.

Answer (score 10):

`setRotate` will replace the matrix operations already performed with the rotation specified.  `postRotate` will use the current matrix values and transform them using the rotation specified.

If you want to translate, then rotate you would `setTranslate`, then `postRotate`.  If you simply want to rotate and are starting with a `new Matrix` then you technically can `setRotate` or `postRotate`, since your matrix will initially be the identity.

I've included the [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to the Matrix object.  I didn't consider it a universally accessible explanation though.